# Arrays in C program

Tags: c, arrays

Here is my C Program Code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned int count = 1; 

int main(void)
{
  int b = 10;
  int a[3];
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 2;
  a[2] = 3; 

  printf("\n b = %d \n",b);
  a[3] = 12; 
  printf("\n b = %d \n",b); 

  return 0;
}
```

And the output as

```
b=10 
b=12
```

Can anyone explain why it is and the reason behind the error.

Comment: `a[3]` - Valid indexes are 0,1,2. Your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: See this - http://ideone.com/AmqjSv. Anything can happen when you are not in your limits.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing beyond the bounds of the array.  This would invoke [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: hi @devnull i am k with ur answer would take pain to see what Mr.Maroun Maroun answer he explains the memory allocation of the variable is that correct . please let me know

Comment: @user3270582 As mentioned, the result is undefined.  Given the specific output in this case, you can _assume_ that `a[3]` _overwrote_ `b`.  But that is not guaranteed to happen.  Your code might as well result in segmentation fault, or might produce the result as `10` or `0`.  Nothing is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing at `a[3] = 12;` to an out of bound index, which is UB and since its UB it means anything can happen so chances are you have just over-written the value at `a[3]` which is the location of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Depending on your result, your memory looked like this:

```
  a[0]   a[1]   a[2]    b   
+------+------+------+----+
|  1   |  2   |  3   | 12 |
+------+------+------+----+
```

`b` is the same as `a[3]` since it "sits" next to it in the memory.

This is only one possible scenario, your program could has a "segmentation fault" or anything else as well.

Comment: How does everyone answer these questions so fast? I type, and then 4 people post 15 seconds before me and 3 thumbs up later... :-/

Comment: @gyeh I'm fast... and furious.

Comment: Hehe, not at fast as Jon Skeet :P

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're accessing `a[3]`, which is the 4th element, but you only defined an array of size 3. As a result, you're getting a pointer to garbage data, which happens to point to the memory location of `b`. So when you assign `a[3]`, you're assigning the memory location of `b`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned int count = 1; 

int main(void)
{
  int b = 10;
  int a[3];
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 2;
  a[2] = 3; 

  printf("\n b = %d \n",b);
  a[3] = 12; 

  printf("\n b = %d \n",b); 

 return 0;
}
```

The pointer memory locations point to the same thing for `a[3]` and `b`:

```
b = 10 
a[3]:0xa
b:0xa

b = 12
```

Now try actually creating an array with four elements. Change `a[3]` to `a[4]`, so that `a[3]` isn't a garbage location. You'll see it works.

Answer (score 0):

The so-called "Undefined Behaviour" can include many kinds of behaviour. Amongst them can be:

- nothing bad happens
- you get a segmentation fault (or any other access violation)
- you destroy/tamper other data structures.

You have the latter here: the variable `b` happens to be in memory directly after the array, so it is modified due to this wrong access.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define a pointer to the address of a[3], and output it. Then you will know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

because if you prints address of both variable b and a[3] like,

```
printf("%u",&b);  
printf("\n %u",&a[3]);
```

then it gives same output for both variable address

Answer (score 0):

Your program results in undefined behavior, answers here explain this "undefined behavior" trying to give some meaning to your output,which is not always true. In-fact i try to run your program and I can see b is printed 10 in both printf and finally i get run time error (I used Visual Studio 2010)